# I have purchased the wordpress theme in Envato like to work it in Sub domain or localhost

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have purchased the wordpress theme in Envato I would like to work it in Sub domain or localhost without disturbing live site. How to use the license
after worked in sub domain we can able to transfer it in live??

After worked in sub domain or Localhost can we able to transfer it in live??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, you can confirm the same with theme author / envato support